# I am seeing duplicate values even with using SELECT DISTINCT and unsure what to do

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, presto, amazon-athena

I wrote a query with multiple different CTEs. And for some reason I am seeing duplicate IDs in the query. I am running the CTEs all separately as well, and I am unsure why but I am seeing duplicate IDs in the signal query. Is there a way I could sort of remove these duplicate values?

```
    WITH ids AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT LOWER(r.entry_uuid) AS RAID
    FROM id_user AS r
    UNION
    SELECT DISTINCT LOWER(wa.sourcereferenceid) AS ID
    FROM accountcreationevent_base AS wa
)
,signal as (
SELECT DISTINCT
rtw.identifiersk
,rtw.createdatetime
,lcd.personid
,pai.ID
,lmd.groupid
,lmd.groupname
,rtw.typecode AS "TC"
,lmmf.date
,CASE WHEN rtw.typecode LIKE 'PRO%' THEN 'Prospect'
               WHEN rtw.typecode LIKE 'CA' THEN  'Cali'
               WHEN rtw.typecode LIKE '%CT%' OR la.description LIKE '%team%' THEN 'Conn'
               END AS Type
FROM traditional_winner rtw
INNER JOIN milestone_fact lmmf ON lmmf.identifierdimsk = rtw.identifierdimsk
INNER JOIN milestone_dim lmd ON lmd.milestonesk = lmmf.milestonesk
LEFT JOIN attributes a ON a.identifierdimsk = rtw.identifierdimsk
LEFT JOIN identifier_dim lid ON lid.identifierdimsk = rtw.identifierdimsk
LEFT JOIN client_dim lcd ON lcd.identifierdimsk = rtw.identifierdimsk
LEFT JOIN (
SELECT party_id as personid, padditional_id as ID 
FROM identifier_current pi
WHERE pi.party_id IN ('AccountId') and party_id is not null and party_id <> '' 
group by party_id, padditional_id
) as pi
ON lcd.personid = pi.personid
AND lmmf.date >= '2022-10-25'
)

,plan as (
    SELECT DISTINCT 
        LOWER(accountid) as "ID"
    FROM acc_data ad
    WHERE (date >= '2022-11-21')
)

,bank as (
    SELECT DISTINCT 
        LOWER(_id) as "ID"
    FROM bank
    WHERE firstaccount_at IS NOT NULL
)

, Rewards as (
    SELECT DISTINCT
        LOWER(id) AS "ID"
        FROM loyal_member
)

--Joining the 4 into 1
--, Joint as (
SELECT DISTINCT
r.ID
,cs.Type
,cs.TC
,CASE WHEN a.ID IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS "Plan Flag"
,CASE WHEN t.RAID IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS "Bank Account Flag"
,CASE WHEN rr.raid IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS "Rewards Flag"
FROM ids r
LEFT JOIN plan a ON r.ID = a.ID
LEFT JOIN Signal cs ON r.ID = cs.ID
LEFT JOIN bank t ON r.ID = t.ID
LEFT JOIN Rewards rr on r.ID = rr.ID
```

Comment: Hi - if you are sure that it is the signal CTE that is causing the issue then that SQL query is probably all you need to include in your question - the rest is unnecessary and is more of a distraction then a help. Can you update your question with some sample results from just running the signal SQL that shows these duplicates? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

One of the possible problems is that `SELECT DISTINCT ...` compares all selected values, i.e.:

```sql
select distinct id1, value
from (values (1, 1),
             (1, 2),
             (1, 1)) as t(id1, value)
```

Will result in two rows:

| id1 | id2 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |

Use `group by` on identifier column to remove duplicates (and appropriate aggregate functions).